# Extract part of time serie with R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a ts (time serie) object in R that contains long periods of missing value. I would like to extract a part of it and keep the time series object.

for example with the AirPassengers Data:

```
class(AirPassengers) 
#output: "ts"
```

but if I extract only the 10 first month

```
AirPassengers[1:10]
#output: [1] 112 118 132 129 121 135 148 148 136 119

class(AirPassengers[1:10])
#output: "numeric"
```

How can I simply extract a part of my time serie without loosing the ts class?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/subsetting-r-time-series-vectors ?

Comment: Thx this is perfect. I never think of searching on stats.stackexchange! I will do so next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was said [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/subsetting-r-time-series-vectors), the solution is to use the `window` function:

```
window(AirPassergers, 1960, c(1960, 4))

     Jan Feb Mar Apr
1960 417 391 419 461
```